# login and password fancybox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

never been exposed to jquery or fancybox for that matter though while creating a website i figured to give fancybox a try for a login screen (pop up frame). I was looking on the fancybox site to download the js jquery and css files put them in the head like it asked and continued to try and implement the password popup but have run into trouble. This is my verticle nav bar and at the bottom of it where it says login I would like that to trigger the popup but no luck. Here is the script:

```
<script>
$("#logID").fancybox({
    'scrolling'     : 'no',
    'titleShow'     : false,
    'onClosed'      : function() {
        $("#login_error").hide();
    }
});</script>
```

and here is the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Ssmzu/

I dont think a jsfiddle would work since i cant put the css files for all of them, but I was wondering how to get this problem resolved. I mean i have the script at the bottom so im not sure what the issue is. Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can add CSS files and JS files with JSFiddle. Look at `external resources` on the left.

Comment: ok will do and post in op

Comment: They do have to be online, as you can't upload them, but you can direct link to the src files from the plugin creator website.

Comment: im not sure how to link them. I found the source on gitHub but im not sure where to go from there?

Comment: `<script src="linktostuffhere"></script>` for JavaScript files and `<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://linkhere.com">`

Comment: `https://github.com/fancyapps/fancyBox/tree/master/source` - is this where you are? Cause you can link files like this: `https://raw.github.com/fancyapps/fancyBox/master/source/jquery.fancybox.js`. You may have to open the files and select the **raw** option on the right for any included files.

Comment: updated the op thanks for being patient